# (:gen-class) and fully qualified symbol

Tags: clojure, namespaces, symbols

I'm wondering why I need to include (:gen-class) to access imported functions from other ns without fully qualify them.

Example:

```
(ns project.core
  (:gen-class))
(defn foo [] "foo")

(ns project.core-test
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [project.core :refer :all]))  
(foo) ;=> "foo"
```

---

```
(ns project.core)
(defn foo [] "foo")

(ns project.core-test
  (:require [project.core :refer :all]))  
(foo) ;=> ComplilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: foo in this context
(project.core/foo) ;=> "foo"
```

I couldn't get my head around this concept.

## EDIT:

I had a typo in the require form. Idk why (:gen-class) solved this problem but now the project works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(:gen-class)` clause in the `ns` form is for Ahead-of-Time compilation (AOT). See https://clojure.org/reference/compilation

Something else must be going wrong in your setup.  My example:

```
> d **/core*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 98 Jan 13 16:15 src/fred/core.clj
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 47 Jan 13 16:15 src/tst/fred/core.clj

src/fred/core.clj
------------------------
(ns fred.core)

(defn foo [] (println "foo you"))

(defn -main []
  (println "main - enter")
  )


src/tst/fred/core.clj
----------------------
(ns tst.fred.core
  (:use fred.core ))

(foo)

> lein test
foo you
```

I get the same results with the `require` version:

```
(ns tst.fred.core
  (:require [fred.core :refer :all]))
(foo)
```

It also works if I paste your code into the repl:

```
~/tmp/fred > lein repl
Clojure 1.9.0

fred.core=> (ns project.core)
nil
project.core=> (defn foo [] "foo")
#'project.core/foo

project.core=> (ns project.core-test
          #_=>   (:require [project.core :refer :all]))  
nil
project.core-test=> (foo)
"foo"
```